# Listening to stdout of a remote machine

Tags: io-redirection, stdout

I'm looking for a way to get a local terminal `tail` log from an stdout execution on a remote machine without *directly* executing with `ssh`.

The general procedure is:

1. The local client machine runs a program that *requests* something to run on the remote server. This request may be denied.
2. The server runs it and somehow pipes the stdout back to the client.

Lets consider `wget` as an example, if I want to initiate a download on the remote server and see the log of the progress on the client side.

So on the client side it should be something like:

```
[complete_this] my.server.io `wget http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip`
```

On the server side we need to run `wget` and redirect stdout to the client

```
wget http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip > [complete_this]
```

I want the local terminal to look like as if I was running that `wget` locally.
Just to clarify the example, no there is not need for the `wget` file to be transferred to the client. Just the download progress on the server side.

Another thing, it would be helpful if the client can lose connection and reconnect at any time to continue viewing the running stdout.

**Edit:**
I'm not trying to avoid ssh. I cannot have the client directly execute the command via ssh to get the stdout. There is a separate a program on the server that chooses to execute, and I just to redirect the command stdout.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what's the purpose of this request. Why do you want to avoid `ssh`? If it's only for reconnecting to a lost session, you could `ssh` to the remote machine, run `screen` there and start `wget` (or whatever long-running program you like). Then you can detach from the `screen` session and later reattach to it. It might also be possible to do this with netcat if you have an open network.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: I'll look into screen. That may be a solution.

Comment: Your vague explanation "*I cannot have the client directly execute the command via ssh to get the stdout. There is a separate a program on the server that chooses to execute, and I just to redirect the command stdout.*" does not explain much. If you run the program from `ssh` you would get `stdout`. It is unclear what you mean with "*here is a separate a program on the server that chooses to execute*" Without more details we don't understand why using `ssh` in the normal way might not work in your use case.

Comment: What interfaces are available to the server?  Clearly not SSH, but something is allowing a request to be made.  How is the request to the server being made by the client?  Web?  Polling a file?

Comment: The server is Ubuntu 18.04 and I can basically put anything I want there to make it fit. It currently runs Jenkins that controls everything. The client is currently ssh-ing to the server to do the request, but it does not execute the program so its kind of a problem getting the stdout. We tried tmux. It works OK, but still not as good as if we had executed the file directly.